# How to remove all characters before last whitespace in R string but with exceptions for certain character sequences?

Tags: r, string, gsub

I've been using the following to remove all characters before the last whitespace in R character strings: `gsub(".*\\s", "", "Big Dog")` returns "Dog" which is perfect.

How could I exclude certain patterns from being removed? For example, let's say I always want to preserve "Big Dog", so if I have the string "Look at that crazy Big Dog", running the `gsub()` (or other code) returns "Big Dog" with that whitespace between Big and Dog retained. In the complete code this is intended for, the equivalent of "Big Dog" isn't dynamic so hard-coding in of "Big Dog" is fine. "Big Dog" will always occupy the last position in a character string too.

Comment: Did you mean to say `Big` is static and known, but `Dog` is not known?

Comment: I think you want `sub("^.*?((?:\\bBig\\s+)?\\S+)$", "\\1", text)`

Comment: Or, `sub("^.*?(Big\\s+Dog|\\S+)$", "\\1", text)`

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I did mean to say Big is static and known but Dog is not. Your solution works very nicely in the larger App this is intended for. Apologies, I rushed my post and should have described this better but you seem to have read my mind!

Comment: Which one? I can post with explanations.

Comment: This one works in my App because it doesn't reference the equivalent of "Dog": `sub("^.*?((?:\\bBig\\s+)?\\S+)$", "\\1", text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not know the `Dog` beforehand, you can use

```r
sub("^.*?((?:\\bBig\\s+)?\\S+)$", "\\1", text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oObyB3/1).  Note the use of the `sub` function, you only need to search and replace once in a string.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `((?:\bBig\s+)?\S+)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:\bBig\s+)?` - an optional sequence of a whole word `Big` (`\b` is a word boundary) and then one or more whitespace chars (`\s+`)
  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

The `\1` replacement puts back the value from Group 1 into the result.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/aEmu46):

```r
x <- c("Look at that crazy Dog", "Look at that crazy Big Dog")
sub("^.*?((?:\\bBig\\s+)?\\S+)$", "\\1", x)
# => [1] "Dog"     "Big Dog"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, otherwise this would look like gibberish to me!

Comment: One more question: how would I expand the list of exceptions from "Big", to for example include "Stray"? In other words, add an "or" in the above `sub()` so it handles both "Big" and "Stray" this way?

Comment: Actually, I need to break my cycle of dependency. This solves my last comment, for any other newbies out there: `sub("^.*?((?:\\b(Big|Stray)\\s+)?\\S+)$", "\\1", x)`

Comment: Use a non-capturing group, `sub("^.*?((?:\\b(?:Big|Stray)\\s+)?\\S+)$", "\\1", x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know all the words and phrases which you don't want to replace at the end of a string, you could use the following whitelist approach:

```r
input <- c("Look at that crazy Dog", "Look at that crazy Big Dog")
keep <- c("Big Dog", "Dog")
regex <- paste0(".*?\\b(", paste(keep, collapse="|"), ")$")
output <- sub(regex, "\\1", input)
output  # [1] "Dog"     "Big Dog"
```

Comment: Your assumption was correct, I know all the character strings I don't want to replace. They are a static group, not dynamic. Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Village.Idyot Pay close attention to the order of terms in my whitelist vector.  "Big Dog" has to come before "Dog" in order to avoid a false match of "Dog" against the larger phrase "Big Dog".